# Absolute width specification for Short

Tags: output-formatting

I repeatedly found myself needing to display a (possibly long) expression to the user inside another structure. [`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short.html) seems perfect for this usecase:

```
Grid[
  {{Short[Range @ 100, 0.3], Short[Range @ 5, 0.3]}}, 
  ItemSize -> {{15, 15}}, Frame -> All]
```

This yields:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which seems perfect. However, simply making the notebook window wider and reevaluating:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is obviously caused by the fact that the second argument of `Short` specifies the maximum width to display relative to the notebook width.

The question is now: How can I efficiently produce an output like in the first image, which does not depend on the notebook window size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

*(Modified to avoid using `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` since it doesn't work correctly for `$Output`)*

You could block [`$Output`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Output) to control the page width being assumed by [`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short). Here is a function to do this:

```
short /: MakeBoxes[short[a_, b_, w_], StandardForm] := With[
    {old = OptionValue[Options @ $Output, PageWidth]},

    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        SetOptions[$Output, PageWidth->w],
 MakeBoxes[Short[a, b], StandardForm],
 SetOptions[$Output, PageWidth->old]
    ]
]
```

The following expression will not change when the notebook window width is changed:

```
Grid[
    {
    {short[Range @ 100, .3, 80], short[Range @ 5, .3, 80]}
    },
    ItemSize->{{15,15}},
    Frame->All
]
```

Comment: What is the story with ``Internal`InheritedBlock`` and friends? Are they going to be exported to system or documented? In the past there was a disclaimer for such answers like "keep in mind this is an undocumented functionality" etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This is exactly the type of solution I was hoping for. One question: On my system (Win 10, 64bit, MMA 11.2), the value of `PageWidth` is not reset after the `InheritedBlock` - do you know why this is case? I could not reproduce the same issue with symbols other than `$Output`. While it's easy to work around the issue by just storing the previous value, it seems odd to me that it does not happen automatically, as you'd except from `InheritedBlock`... (as similar construct with `Block` & `Options` also seems to have the same issue with `$Output` options)

Comment: @Mathe172 I didn't realize `InheritedBlock` didn't work for `$Output`. I'll modify my answer.